# Error connecting external DB to Rails 4 App

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am attempting to add a Postgresql Redshift Database to my Rails 4 app, for use locally and in production. I am testing in Development first.

I have altered my database.yml file to look like this:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: new_db
  pool: 5
  username: test
  password: password
  host: test_db.us-east-1.redshift.amazonaws.com
  port: 5439
```

Now, when I hit `localhost:3000` I get this error:

> permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "warning"
>   : SET client_min_messages TO 'warning'

I can't seem to find out what is causing this - It seems like maybe my new DB isn't allow the SET command? I'm not really sure, but any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just answered this somewhere else, but I had the same issues today, here's what I did and it's working now:

```
#app/models/data_warehouse.rb
class DataWarehouse < ActiveRecord::Base                      
  establish_connection "redshift_staging"
  #or, if you want to have a db per environment
  #establish_connection "redshift_#{Rails.env}"
end
```

Note that we are connecting on 5439, not the default 5432 so I specify the port
Also, I specify a schema, beta, which is what we use for our unstable aggregates, you could either have a different db per environment as mentioned above, or use various schemas and include them in the search path for ActiveRecord

```
#config/database.yml
redshift_staging:                                                          
  adapter: postgresql                                                      
  encoding: utf8                                                           
  database: db03                                                         
  port: 5439                                                               
  pool: 5                                                                  
  schema_search_path: 'beta'                                                                                          
  username: admin                                                        
  password: supersecretpassword                                               
  host: db03.myremotehost.us  #your remote host here, might be an aws url from Redshift admin console
```

###OPTION 2, a direct PG Connection

```
  class DataWarehouse < ActiveRecord::Base                      

    attr_accessor :conn                                                       

    def initialize                                                            
      @conn = PG.connect(                                                     
       database: 'db03',                                                   
       port: 5439,                                                           
       pool: 5,                                                              
       schema_search_path: 'beta',                                           
       username: 'admin',                                                  
       password: 'supersecretpassword',                                         
       host: 'db03.myremotehost.us'                                               
      )                                                                       
    end    
  end


[DEV] main:0> redshift = DataWarehouse
E, [2014-07-17T11:09:17.758957 #44535] ERROR -- : PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice" : SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'
(pry) output error: #<ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR:  permission denied to set parameter "client_min_messages" to "notice" : SET client_min_messages TO 'notice'>
```

**UPDATE:**

#### I ended up going with option 1, but using this adapter for now for multiple reasons:

https://github.com/fiksu/activerecord-redshift-adapter

Reason 1: ActiveRecord postgresql adapter sets client_min_messages
Reason 2: adapter also attempts to set Time Zone, which redshift doesn't allow (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/c_redshift-and-postgres-sql.html)
Reason 3: Even if you change the code in ActiveRecord for the first two errors, you run into additional errors that complain that Redshift is using Postgresql 8.0, at that point I moved on to the adapter, will revisit and update if I find something better later.

#### I renamed my table to base_aggregate_redshift_tests (notice plural) so ActiveRecord was easily able to connect, if you can't change your table names in redshift use the set_table method I have commented out below

```
#Gemfile:
gem 'activerecord4-redshift-adapter', github: 'aamine/activerecord4-redshift-adapter'
```

## Option 1

```
#config/database.yml
redshift_staging:                                                                                                             
  adapter: redshift                                                                                                           
  encoding: utf8                                                                                                              
  database: db03                                                                                                           
  port: 5439                                                                                                                  
  pool: 5                                                                                                                     
  username: admin                                                                                                
  password: supersecretpassword                                                                                                  
  host: db03.myremotehost.us                                                                                                       
  timeout: 5000   

#app/models/base_aggregates_redshift_test.rb
#Model named to match my tables in Redshift, if you want you can set_table like I have commented out below

class BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  establish_connection "redshift_staging"
  self.table_name = "beta.base_aggregates_v2"
end
```

## in console using self.table_name -- notice it queries the right table, so you can name your models whatever you want

```
[DEV] main:0> redshift = BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest.first                                                                    
D, [2014-07-17T15:31:58.678103 #43776] DEBUG -- :   BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest Load (45.6ms)  SELECT "beta"."base_aggregates_v2".* FROM "beta"."base_aggregates_v2" LIMIT 1
```

## Option 2

```
#app/models/base_aggregates_redshift_test.rb
class BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest < ActiveRecord::Base
  set_table "beta.base_aggregates_v2"

  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(
    adapter: 'redshift',
    encoding: 'utf8',
    database: 'staging',
    port: '5439',
    pool: '5',
    username: 'admin',
    password: 'supersecretpassword',
    search_schema: 'beta',
    host: 'db03.myremotehost.us',
    timeout: '5000'
  )

end

#in console, abbreviated example of first record, now it's using the new name for my redshift table, just assuming I've got the record at base_aggregates_redshift_tests because I didn't set the table_name

[DEV] main:0> redshift = BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest.first
D, [2014-07-17T15:09:39.388918 #11537] DEBUG -- :   BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest Load (45.3ms)  SELECT "base_aggregates_redshift_tests".* FROM "base_aggregates_redshift_tests" LIMIT 1
#<BaseAggregatesRedshiftTest:0x007fd8c4a12580> {
                                                :truncated_month => Thu, 31 Jan 2013 19:00:00 EST -05:00,
                                                :dma => "Cityville",
                                                :group_id => 9712338,
                                                :dma_id => 9999 
                                                }
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

What's your postgresql version? or middle ware version? it's not a original postgresql version?

you can use \set VERBOSITY verbose
and then do it again, find which function@code raise the error.
and then analyze why you cann't set client_min_messages.

I use postgresql 9.3.3 no this problem.
super and normal user can set client_min_messages correct.

```
digoal=# \c digoal digoal
You are now connected to database "digoal" as user "digoal".
digoal=> set client_min_messages=debug;
SET
digoal=> set client_min_messages=warning;
SET
digoal=> SET client_min_messages TO 'warning';
SET
digoal=> \c postgres digoal
You are now connected to database "postgres" as user "digoal".
postgres=> SET client_min_messages TO 'warning';
SET
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by opening up the postgresql adapter for Activerecord and commenting out all of the SET commands.

However, this is not a best practice at all. At the end of editing the postgresql adapter I was faced with errors due to an outdated postgres version (80002).

The right answer is just updating postgres, which unfortunately isn't possible amongst my shared Redshift DB that lives at Amazon.

Comment: Or you can modify your postgresql version's code, and comment out these errors code part, ignore these error. then recompile it .